# How do I start ultra-repl

Tags: node.js, read-eval-print-loop

I'm using `node js v0.12.4` on Win 8 and I have installed `ultra-repl` using:

```
npm install ultra-repl
```

How do I start it? I've tried to start using:

```
node ultra-repl.js
```

but I get the error:

```
d:\Development\Private\WorkspaceServer\messaging\node_modules\ultra-repl\lib\ScopedModule.js:81
    if (NativeModule.exists(request)) {
                    ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'exists' of undefined
    at Function._resolveFilename (d:\Development\Private\WorkspaceServer\messaging\node_modules\ultra-repl\lib\ScopedModule.js:81:21)
    at Function._load (d:\Development\Private\WorkspaceServer\messaging\node_modules\ultra-repl\lib\ScopedModule.js:102:33)
    at Object.<anonymous> (d:\Development\Private\WorkspaceServer\messaging\node_modules\ultra-repl\index.js:3:30)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (d:\Development\Private\WorkspaceServer\messaging\node_modules\ultra-repl\bin\ultra-repl.js:2:18)
```

**Update:**
Unfortunately, this no longer works since `arguments.callee.caller` was deprecated.

Does this mean that ultra-repl is not working at all anymore?

Comment: I have since created something similar to ultra-repl, you can check it out here: https://github.com/skerit/janeway

Comment: @skerit Thanks but I've decided to let node.js be for now.... again. It's just not there yet... still.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be broken since at least v0.12.2.
There's an [open bug report](https://github.com/Benvie/Node.js-Ultra-REPL/issues/31) on Github, but no workaround reported yet.

<sup>( I just realised you commented on that bug report, so you obviously already know about it. I'll leave the link in my answer for the sake of others, though. )</sup>

If you're willing to use an earlier version of node, you could install one with [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)* and try installing ultra-repl for that version.

* Note: NVM doesn't support Windows, but there are a couple of alternatives for Windows (which seem to share the same interface) linked on its page.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not willing to downgrade. I pretty much left the node.js world for my projects. It's just not "business" enough yet. I'm running nvm on Windows and that seems to be working fine but I only use it for playing around. Thanks anyway!